# Use Cloudflare WAF to block all URLs except home page and one subdirectory

Tags: cloudflare, access-control

I want to block all paths except `/English/` and the home page `www.example.com` in Cloudflare WAF. If I allow the English category, I would expect access to be allowed to all URLs from this category. The URLs for other categories should be blocked.